# How to build a silent installer

Tags: linux, installation, development-environment, silent-installer

What are the ways to create a silent installer for a .bin file.

So, currently, I have a **installer.bin** file that installs the software on a VM (Linux machine) using GUI wizard. This increases the load on the server so, I am looking for different ways to create a silent installer that does not uses GUI, instead uses CLI for inputs/outputs.
Currently to install the application I run the following command:

```bash
$ sudo ./installer.bin -f installer.properties -i gui
```

The file **installer.properties** is a response file that has input parameters needed by the gui. The gui takes some input parameters like location, where to install the software etc.

There is one methods, I found on the internet.

**Method**: I found the -silent flag and passing in the response file.

```bash
$ sudo ./installer.bin -f installer.properties -i silent
```

This method doesn't seem to work well and throws the error: "Installer User Interface Mode Not Supported".

I am looking for various technologies or software or method that can be used to do the task above. I have looked at many other questions. I do not know whether this question has been asked before or not.
I wanted to know, is it possible to do so without changing the codebase. If so, how ?

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard of an installer being used on Linux systems. Which installer software are you using?

Comment: @Julia, It's a desktop application build file that opens a GUI wizard. I wanted to get rid of that and make a command line tool for user interaction and installation.